# How to find combinations of columns 1 and 2 that do not exist in an SQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose the table is:

| employee_id | branch | role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | admin |
| 2 | A | engineer |
| 3 | A | finance |
| 4 | B | admin |
| 5 | B | finance |
| 6 | C | engineer |

How can I find the departments that do not have all the roles?

In this example:

- Department A has all the roles.
- Department B does not have engineer role.
- Department C does not have admin and finance roles.

What would be the SQL query to get this result?

Ideally, the output should be

| branch | role |
| --- | --- |
| B | engineer |
| C | admin |
| C | finance |

Answer (score 0):

We can use a calendar table left anti join approach here:

```sql
SELECT b.branch, r.`role`
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT branch FROM yourTable) b
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT `role` FROM yourTable) r
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON t.branch = b.branch AND
       t.`role` = r.`role`
WHERE t.branch IS NULL
ORDER BY SELECT b.branch, r.`role`;
```

Note that `role` was a reserved keyword in MySQL versions earlier than 8+.  If you are using an earlier version, you should avoid using `role` as a column name.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `CROSS JOIN` to build all possible combinations of branch and role and then `NOT EXISTS` to exclude those combinations that really exist in the table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.branch, r.roles
FROM (SELECT branch FROM yourtable) b
CROSS JOIN (SELECT roles FROM yourtable) r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourtable 
WHERE branch = b.branch AND roles = r.roles)
ORDER BY b.branch, r.roles;
```

Note: The column "role" was renamed to "roles" in my query to prevent that "role" will be read as SQL key word.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation.

If you want just the branches:

```
SELECT branch
FROM tablename
GROUP BY branch 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT role) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT role) FROM tablename);
```

If you want all the rows of the table for the branches returned by the above query use also the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE branch IN (
  SELECT branch
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY branch 
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT role) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT role) FROM tablename)
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/yrIJ9DRx).